# afterColumn not working in DB liquibase 3.2.2

Tags: mysql, database, ant, liquibase

According to [this link](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1745), `afterColumn` works in DB liquibase now.

But its still not working on my system. I am using DB liquibase 3.2.2 and MySQL and have integrated DB liquibase with ant.

Comment: The fix version in the link you provided shows fixVersion 3.3.0...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This info is not visible when I open the link from my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The *desktop view* of the [web page](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1745) you linked to states that this issue was fixed in version **3.3.0**.

This information seems to be missing from the *mobile view* of the page.